# How to render an animation through command prompt in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, command-line

I have been trying to render a 180 frames animation from command prompt with `blender -b file.blend -a` but instead of giving me an MP4 file it rendered me each frame in JPEG.

Do you know how can I make the final result a video file ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you never changed the output to mpeg 4, but you should never encode directly to video anyway. Encode to image and then render the images to video.

Answer (score 1):

one way to achieve this is to change your output settings in your project -> file format -> video.

Then use your command in command prompt.

[image]